# BackgroundWorker CancelAsync disables ProgressChanged?

Tags: backgroundworker

In my testing, it appears that once `CancelAsync` is called, `BackgroundWorker` will no longer honor the `ReportProgress` method in `ProgressChanged`. `ReportProgress` executes without an exception, but `ProgressChanged` stops actually doing anything. I'm imagining something like:

```
<code>
if (CancellationPending) return;
</code>
```

in `ProgressChanged`.

Can anyone else confirm or contradict this claim?

While I can see why it might have seemed like a good idea, it assumes that the command object would never do any more user notification once `CancelAsync` has been called, which seems bogus. It also actually means that you have to at a minimum always check for cancellation before you call `ReportProgress`, which is pretty klunky. Even then I don't think it would be foolproof against a race (said the threading numbskull ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was my own code that was preventing ReportProgress from working. Duh. Verified that ReportProgress is called even after CancelAsync is called and CancellationPending is set to true.